# How can I refresh a route every time it is accessed in Vue Router 4?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have setup a `route` in `vue-router 4` that should load a `component` dynamically depending on whether the user is logged in or not. I did it like this (there may be a better way?):

```
import Personal from '../views/Personal.vue';
import Public from '../views/Public.vue';
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: async () => {
            const isLoggedIn = await authenticateUser();
            if (isLoggedIn == true) {
                return Personal
            } else {
               return Public
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The `App.vue` file is this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <Site-Header></Site-Header>
          <router-view></router-view>
    <Site-Footer></Site-Footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is that if a user logs in from the homepage route with path of `'/'`, he doesn't navigate away from this route. Instead I would like `vue-router` to just load the `Personal` component instead.

The switch between `Personal` and `Public` only seems to work if I hard refresh the page, otherwise no changes happen. So if a user logs in, they still see the `Public.vue` component, then after a page refresh they see the `Personal.vue` component. If they then logout, they still see the `Personal.vue` component until they refresh the page.

How could I force vue-router to analyse the route after log-in/log-out and load the correct component?

Comment: A better solution than dynamic components (especially a root component that gets loaded in first) is to use a combination of [router meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) & [route navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

Comment: @Sensanaty I don't want the URL to change from `/` to say `/personal`. I want the view to change on the same route of `/`.

Comment: In that case you can utilize [named views](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html) and simply switch between two routes using a `v-if`

`<router-view v-if="loggedIn" name="Personal" /> <router-view v-else name="Public" />`

Comment: @Sensanaty That is what I'm trying to do in the `routes[]` part but because the path does not change, I am not getting a reload of the route. Updated my question with more code.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how named views work. I've made a quick example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-surf-lcq3p?file=/src/lib/router.js) that you can check out that demonstrates how you can achieve this using Named Views. Note that the router `components` definition is PLURAL, rather than singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have multiple routes utilizing the same path, your best bet is using [Named Views](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html). You can define the default component for your index, or `/` path to be your `Public` component, while conditionally selecting a different component using `v-if` in your template.

You could define your routes as:

```js
routes: [
  {
    components: {
      default: Public,
      Personal: Personal
    },
    name: "index",
    path: "/"
  }
]
```

Important to note that the syntax here differs. The `component` field here has to be pluralized in order for this to work, so it has to be `components`.

Then in your root template that's calling the views, you can then use a simple `v-if` to switch between them, depending on whether the user is logged in or not. How you store that information is up to you, so just adapt the below code to reflect your own app's logic

```html
<!-- The default is Public, so you don't have to provide the name here -->
<router-view v-if="!user.loggedIn" />
<router-view v-else name="Personal" />
```

You can see this in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-surf-lcq3p?file=/src/App.vue)